# iron-icon resize issue on mobile device mode

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an `iron-icon` as below, it displays fine on browser, but when I switch device mode to iphone 6 it becomes very small. Same is the case with `paper-icon-button`. But when I wrap the icon in a `paper-button` it is resized correctly but has lot of padding/margin which I don't want. How do I get `iron-icon` to be compatible with all device modes.

This doesnt work:

```
<iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
```

This works, but has lot of padding:

```
<paper-button>
<iron-icon icon="arrow-drop-down"></iron-icon>
</paper-button>
```